# "char*" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPWSTR"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am getting an E0167 Error code using Visual Studio:

> "argument of type "char*" is incompatible with parameter type of "LPWSTR"

This program is for an API Plugin I am building.

I am getting an error with username -- in the `GetUserName(username, &username_len)`

```
// Auto populate Operator 
char username[UNLEN + 1];
DWORD username_len = UNLEN + 1;
CString User = username;
GetUserName(username, &username_len);
pIndexingOperator->szFieldValue.Set(User);
```

Comment: You are probably compiling for unicode. So `GetUserName` is actually calling `GetUserNameW` which expects a `LPWSTR` parameter.

Comment: A bigger issue is that it is important you know why such an error occurs.  Knowing the difference between narrow, wide, UTF-8, etc. characters is essential knowledge for any programmer..

Answer (score 1):

`LPWSTR` is defined as `wchar_t *`, not `char *`. You need to define your buffer as such, and fill it with proper wide characters.

Answer (score 1):

`LPWSTR` is wide characters array `(wchar_t *)` more information about wide charachters here : [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character)

you should be able to convert `char *` to `LPWSTR` as folows :

`C`

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

LPWSTR char2lpwstr ( const char *str ) {
    unsigned int length = strlen ( str ) + 1 ;
    wchar_t  *ws = new wchar_t [ length ] ;
    swprintf ( ws , length , L"%hs" , str );
    return ( LPWSTR )ws ;
}
```

`C++`

```
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
#include <string>

LPWSTR char2lpwstr ( const char *str ) {
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
    return converter.from_bytes(str).c_str ( ) ;
}
```